# How to have Controller for a Subviewfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I like to have a controller for multiple views. The structure should look like these.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible or anybody have an good idea too avoid view names like `AddQuantityProduct.cshtml`, `AddMatrixProduct.cshtml`.

Comment: What about MVC Areas? You can have Product area and then AddProduct controller with own sets of action\views

Comment: I will think about it.

Comment: You could write a custom razor view engine that looks in all sub folders based on a custom convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't think it's a good idea to blow your controller up with so much functionality, you can easily do that by specifying the full path of the view in each action.

Example:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View("~/Views/Products/Add/MatrixProduct.cshtml");
}
```